# How to move back a command in WP-CLI from wp shell?

Tags: wp-cli

Absolute beginner here... I'm familiarizing myself with WP-CLI, and I typed "wp shell" taking me to wp> (input box)

How do I escape wp shell and go back to ["username" /home/public] (input box)?

I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 2):

From [wp-cli.org](http://wp-cli.org/blog/wp-shell.html): *Type "exit" to close session.* Alternatively you can try hitting `Ctrl+C` or `Cmd+C` for Mac I think.